# how to fetch record count while load data infile mysql

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5...);
```

here how can i get records count which been inserted

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please post more of the code you have written so far and have a look at this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You run a select count(*) in another window

Comment: here the case is like we used to load files daily so i cant take count(*) as it contains other files count